# Get-Childitem: Illegal character path error

Tags: windows, powershell

I am new to powershell and new to programming as well. 
I am trying to get a script to search for all type of files and put it into a folder.

But it is giving me error;

`Get-Childitem:illegal character path`

```
$extensions = '*.xls*', '*.docx*', '*.txt', '*.pdf', '*.jpg', '*.pub'

Get-Content C:\scripts\computer\computers.txt | % {
  $ComputerName = $_

  $dst ="\\192.168.1.11\public\$ComputerName" 
  $src ="\\$ComputerName\*``\desktop"


  New-Item -ItemType Directory $dst

  Get-Childitem $src -Include $extensions -Recurse -Force |
    Copy-Item -Destination $dst
}
```

What is causing this?

Comment: This is the problem: `\\$ComputerName\*``\desktop`

Answer (score 1):

As @arco444 stated, the problem is with this line:

```
$src ="\\$ComputerName\*``\desktop"
```

The grave accent (`` ` ``) is an escape character. There are various uses of escape characters in PowerShell, such as creating a new line (`` `n ``), or escaping an else-interpreted symbol (`` `# `` won't create a comment, for example).

I hope that clears up the question.

Answer (score 0):

You load a list into $ComputerName, but do not trim of the carriage return/line feed at the end of every $_

So $ComputerName = $_.trim()

Try again and see that it now works.  Old IBM typewriter logic.